# In Dart, when I delay the exec of a method, the value of its parameter is the one when the delayed call is requested, or when the method is executed?

Tags: dart

```
//Time 0

Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:10),() => _someMethod(variableX));

//...other stuff
```

_someMethod() is called with the value of variableX at time 0 or with the value of variableX at time 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10. 

The `variableX` variable reference is evaluated when the `_someMethod(variableX)` code is run, which happens in ten seconds.

If you want to keep the current value of a mutable variable, you need to keep it in a separate variable:

```dart
var currentX = variableX;
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () => _someMethod(currentX));
```